# GTM Blacklist specific div by class

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager

I'd like to use the [GTM blacklist](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#restricting-tag-deployment) feature for only not send the **input** values of the HTML input fields that belongs to a specific class.

So far I've been able to blacklist all the clicks, but this is just too much.

In the below example, I'd like not to send the `inputPassword` input (see the `gtm-blacklist` class)

```
<form novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="form_login" ng-submit="login(user)">
   <div class="form-group">
      <!--<label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"> Email</label>-->
      <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-initial="" required="">
      <div class="field-underline"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched gtm-blacklist" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" ng-initial="" required="">
      <div class="field-underline"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="forgot-pass btn btn-link">Forgot password</button>
      <button type="button" class="show-new-customer btn btn-link">Create an Account</button>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-login" disabled="disabled" ng-disabled="!user.email || form_login.$error.email"> Sign in</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't it work when you define your blacklist like this: dataLayer = [{'gtm.blacklist': ['gtm-blacklist']}];  OR  dataLayer = [{'gtm.blacklist': ['inputPassword']}]; ?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work like that :(

Comment: Without more information on your GTM setup, this might not work; but you could add class NOT EQUAL TO `gtm-blacklist` on your triggers to prevent them firing tags

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaltley, that isn't how the blacklist works.

The blacklist is for restricting which tags, triggers, and variables are allowed on a page.

To stop users with GTM access from scraping passwords, you could instead restrict the use of custom HTML and custom JavaScript on your login page.To do this, blacklist the customScripts class.

```
dataLayer = [{
  ...
  'gtm.blacklist': ['customScripts']
}];
```

This works because none of the inbuilt variables will return an input value.

Comment: Does this technique work for single page applcations?